# About the read() in unistd.h (C++)

Tags: c++, unistd.h

all, I am designing a Key-Value server, and when I wrote the client, and I found a really strange thing,see the simplified code:

```
while(1)
{
    printf("->:");
    read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, sizeof(buf));
    write(client_sock, buf, sizeof(buf));
    int m = read(client_sock, buf, sizeof(buf));
    buf[m] = '\0';
    printf("%s", buf);
}
```

when I run the program, it first ask for input, so I input something, but nothing happen!
(the server runs well, and it well echo something, when I use other client)

then I change the code only one line:

```
printf("\n->:");
```

then it runs well!  why? why "\n" can change the output? I guess it maybe the read() , but I can't explain it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`printf(3)` is part of the C standard IO library, which performs internal buffering to provide performance improvements.

There are three types of buffering: none, line, and block.

Which buffering is applied is determined in part by whether the descriptor being written to is `2` or not, and if it is connected to a terminal. (See `isatty(3)`.)

If the printing is done to stderr (`2`) then no buffering is done.

If the printing is done to any other descriptor, then the behavior changes if it is a terminal or not: if output is a terminal, then the output is *line buffered*. If the output is *not* a terminal (file, pipe, socket, etc.) then the output is *block buffered*.

When line buffered, it waits for the `\n` before printing anything. (Or if you write enough to overflow the internal buffers before sending a `\n`.)

What I'd recommend instead is the following:

```
printf("->:");
fflush(stdout);
read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, sizeof(buf));
/* ... */
printf("%s\n", buf);
```

It's a small change; you won't get a pointless empty line at program start, and the prompt should show up .. promptly.

You can use the `setvbuf(3)` function to change the buffering for your stream once, at start up, and never need to flush it again, if you would rather.

```
int err = setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
/* check err */
```

Answer (score 3):

Standard output is line-buffered by default. If you don't write a complete line, the output will be held in the buffer until you do. You can use `fflush` to flush the stream or `setbuf` to change the buffering mode.